# is there a way/software to scrape all verified accounts that have a specific link in bio as a CTA on insta/twitter/tiktok?

Tags: web-scraping

is there a way/software to scrape all verified accounts that have a specific link in bio as a CTA on insta/twitter/tiktok?

aka

"cameo.com" / "linktree.com" / "gumroad.com/" / "whop.com" [examples]

and slap it into a csv file?

selenium maybe, but it didnt work